# WCF returning error after 30min-1hr of idle

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I have this problem on WCF that probably a configuration settings issue. My service has httpbasicbindng,webhttpbinding and nettcp binding. Call to service to either of these endpoints works perfectly. But when the service is idle for like 30minutes to 1hr with no activity, no request or anything that interacts with the service. When you do a request for it, it won't process that request anymore. The request is being denied by the service. This is the details I get when I do a request.

```
{
"Detail": "The server rejected the upgrade request."
}
```

My service is hosted under IIS7. And I have a running form that holds the connection for NetTCP.

***Update***

I enabled system diagnostic on both clients/server. I found that the issue is caused by another service where my wcf app is connected to. That service is not responding because it limits the request. I increased the amount of request to that service and the issue went away.

Comment: Are you re-creating proxy when calling service or reusing existing? Can you turn on diagnostics on the client/server and get more info? SvcConfigEditor can help you setup diagnostics [pic here](http://petarvucetin.me/blog/2008/06/7-hidden-gems-tools-everyday-wcf-wf-developers/) [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)

Comment: Have you implemented IErrorHandler in there at all? If so - what error does it catch?